# Two Submit Buttons to Two Controllers on One Ruby Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, form-submit

I have one submit button that works on this form:

**_form.html.erb**

```html
<%= form_for(@goal) do |f| %>
  <% if @goal.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@goal.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this goal from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @goal.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="america">
<form>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Goal' %>
  </div>
    <div class="date-group">
      <label> Deadline: </label>
      <%= f.date_select :deadline, :order => [:month, :day, :year], class: 'date-select' %>
    </div>

<div class="america2">
  <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn") do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to goals_path, class: 'btn' do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to @goal, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn' do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
  <% end %>
</div>
  </form>
</div>
<% end %>
```

How do I add another submit button that leads to a different controller/model/index? How it functions: Once a user completes a self-imposed goal they can check it off. I want the check it off submit button to update the goal from the goals index by sending it to the accomplished_goals index.

Besides adding something to this view form do I need to add anything to either the GoalsController or the AccomplishedGoalsController?

Thanks for the help! I couldn't find a solution from the other StackOverFlow questions by a similar name.

Comment: can you please explain it clearly and remove all the unnecessary code. I'm not getting it. For the second submit button, just add a link_to: <%= link_to 'text', {:controller => "name of controller", :action => "index",  :paramname => paramvalue }, :method => "post or get" %> http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell from your description what you're trying to achieve and your html seems convoluted with lots of opening tags that have no closing tags.

From what I gather, you're approaching this the wrong way. Rather than having a Goal model and an AccomplishedGoal model, I recommend just having a Goal model with a bool column named "accomplished" (true/false). You can then just create a single form to update this field. To find all accomplished goals, you can use [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes).

If this is not what you're looking for, please be more descriptive of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help sorry to be a pain. Here's as far as I code get with your suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27761029/how-to-show-true-false-boolean-in-seperate-tables-on-the-same-index-page. Thanks again your suggestion saved me a lot of heartache.

Comment: I recommend you read through the official Rails guides (especially on MVC and again on scopes) and work through a basic tutorial. It is evident, that you did not spend time trying to understand scopes.